# One Consumer consuming from two different topics on two separate clusters

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have one consumer which I am initializing with a list of brokers (`bootstrap.servers`). Now in most use cases the list is made of interconnected brokers. So if one connects, then kafka will automatically populate the list of other brokers.

However, I may have a use case in which I want one consumer to consume from two topics `test1` and `test2` which are present on two separate clusters `C1` and `C2`. I thought of using the consumer API to give the kafka consumer two brokers, one from each of the clusters.

```
    Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
    kafkaProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "b1:9092,b2:9092");
```

Here `b1` is a broker from `C1` and `b2` is a broker from `C2`

Then I would use `consumer.subscribe(new ArrayList<String>() {{"test1","test2"}})`.

I wanted to know if this is the right approach or if it would even work. Please tell me if yu want me to share any extra information

Comment: You need to use MirrorMaker to send data from one cluster to the other to consume from both topics given one single Kafka cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have two different cluster topic under the same consumer, when the consumer starts will fetch all the brokers and topic on  cluster and try to find the topic of another cluster, since one of the topic is not existed it will result error message

```
Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 20 : {second-cluster-testtopic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

we can have same consumer for two different topics under same cluster, but advisable scenarios like two topics having same type of data

Answer (score 2):

Just tested by putting two different clusters comma separated in prop-

`ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"prod-cluster:9092,dev-cluster:9092"`

It picked up dev-cluster details and processed request. Reversing the sequence reverses the cluster picked by consumer. No error thrown.

As per Kafka documentation intention of having string separated multiple brokers is for fault tolerance and not simultaneous connection. At a time a consumer will connect with one broker only which internally provides metadata of corresponding cluster like partition details, leaders etc.